# SQLite error - parameter substitution

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, parameter-passing

I'm getting an error in this code that completely baffles me, any help, ideas, suggestions are appreciated.

I have the following code in place:

```
   Sub addauthorsearch(ByVal objconn As SQLiteConnection, ByVal author As String, ByVal searchname As String)
        Dim myTrans As SQLiteTransaction
        Dim objCommand As SQLiteCommand
        Dim authorid As Integer
        myTrans = objconn.BeginTransaction
<< snipped  authorid is retrieved in here>>
       objCommand = objconn.CreateCommand()
        'objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [authorsearch] ([searchid],[authorid] ) VALUES ('" & searchname & "', '" & authorid  & "');"
        objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [authorsearch] ([searchid],[authorid] ) VALUES (@name, @id);"
        objCommand.Parameters.Clear()
        objCommand.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@name", searchname))  ' * error occurs here
        objCommand.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@id", authorid))

        Try
            objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " & ex.Message)
        Catch ex As SQLiteException
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " & ex.Message)

        End Try
        myTrans.Commit()
```

the database is defined (in the create) as

```
CREATE TABLE authorsearch 
    (searchid VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
     authorid INTEGER REFERENCES author (authorid))
```

the error being returned is an `InvalidCastException`, specifically Conversion from string "a-itmatov, chingiz" to type `Integer` is not valid.
`searchID` is defined as `vchar`, and I see no reason that anything should be attempting to convert it to an integer.
The non parameterized statement works, however it fails on names that contain a single quote ( O'Neil for example ) for obvious reasons.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

On a related question, obviously translating C# code helps and there are a couple of forums where sqlite and c# are discussed, does anyone know of a forum where VB.NET and sqlite have an area.